# Simple image drawing Java

Tags: java, image, file, graphics, jpanel

How are images drawn in java, im at a loss. I've managed to get a BufferedImage from a file and then use getGraphics() and g.drawImage() but this doesnt work. I've seen suggestions for a class called paintComponent() then super(g).paintComponent but this doesnt work.

I have a JPanel called panel and a JFrame called frame. I was originally trying to add an image to the panel but i thought just Graphics would work. I want an image to draw across my entire gui, ive got two ints for width and height so not a problem.

Ive looked at java docs and other posts without finding an answer, this is my last resort :/

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you want to generate images in java?

Comment: I want to show a predefined image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways. The simplest would be to wrap the BufferedImage in an ImageIcon and apply it to a JLabel...

```
BufferedImage img = ...
JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img));
// add the label to something ...
```

Take a look at [How to use labels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) for more details

If you need something more complicated, you should use look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Drawing an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/drawimage.html) for mor details

If you need to resize the image, take a look at [Java: maintaining aspect ratio of JPanel background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959758/java-maintaining-aspect-ratio-of-jpanel-background-image/11959928#11959928)

Comment: This is very helpful, didnt think of using JLabels, might be my answer

Comment: Remember, JLabel is just container, so if you need to, you can simply set a layout manager on it and add other components to it...makes for a nice background component...